# Is there a listener for the Data Service on/off event menu option

Tags: blackberry

I'm trying to detect the event of someone switching data services on/off from the options --> mobile network menu.

I've had limited success with [RadioStatusListener](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/RadioStatusListener.html) and the pdpStateChange event. It fires on some phones/OS's

I think I'm able to detect most other ways you might lose/gain your data service but this one seems like my white whale.

I use BB OS's 4.5 and up.

Thanks in advance for any help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any direct way of listening for the configuration change you've highlighted, but if you want to know whether you have data coverage at all, you can use the [CoverageStatusListener](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/CoverageStatusListener.html)

Comment: Thanks Michael, I didn't notice CoverageStatusListener picking up on the loss of data coverage from this option but I will try again.

Comment: You're right, I'm not sure what made me think this wasn't working. I must have been doing something silly. Thanks